# ¿Cómo crear una lista de dos dimensiones con bucles anidados?

Tags: r, bucles

Quiero crear una lista de dos dimensiones anidando dos bucles `for` de la siguiente forma:

```
a <- list()

for(i in (1:3)){
  for (j in (1:2)){
    list[[i]][j]<-rnorm(2)
  }
}
```

Sin embargo obtengo el error:

> error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: error:   object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando hacer es una lista de listas, es decir una lista dónde cada elemento sea a su vez otra lista. Tienes algunos problemas en tu código:

**Falta de definición de las "sublistas"**: Correctamente creas la lista inicial mediante `a <- list()`, pero no haces lo mismo para cada elemento de la mismas, es decir: `a[[i]] <- list()`

Por otro lado tienes **un error tipográfico**, ya que no es `list[[i]][j]<-rnorm(2)` sino más bien `a[[i]][[j]] <- rnorm(2)`, nota que asignamos la nueva lista a `a` y el uso de los dobles corchetes `[[` para poder acceder al elemento en sí.

Tu código finalmente podría quedar así:

```
a <- list()
for(i in (1:3)){
  a[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in (1:2)){
    a[[i]][[j]] <- rnorm(2)
  }
}
```